# How to sync data between web and native app without using AsyncTask/timer that makes API call? And then send a push notification to the device?

Tags: android, synchronization

I'm trying to syncronize message chats between a web version of an app and the native Android app. When I send/receive a message on the web version, it should automatically sync on the native version and show up on my list of messages. How can I do that without having an AsyncTask that runs in the background and calls the API every 5 seconds?

And whats the best method for making that push notification to the phone too, Google Cloud Platform? Ideally one that is free.

Comment: Every 5 seconds seems excessive. Have you not seen SyncAdapter or AlarmManager in your research?

Comment: FWIW, if you used Firebase, or an equivalent "realtime database", this feature would be included in that library

Comment: `without having an AsyncTask` why? Also do you mind uusing any other asynchronous mechanism?

Comment: I mean, Messenger does that instantly I send a message on FB messenger, so there must be some way to do it right?

Comment: socket connection, push notifications...